# Mapping of theoretical consistency models to C++ memory ordering models

Tags: c++, theory, memory-barriers, consistency

Wikipedia page for [Consistency models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model#Weak_memory_consistency_models) list four consistency models for shared memory architecture as which require specific explicit synchronization by the programmers (in order from strongest to weakest):

1. Weak ordering:
   Classifies memory operations into two categories: 'data operations' and 'synchronization operations'. Synchronization operations signal the processor to make sure it has completed and seen all previous operations done by all processors.
2. Release Consistency:
   Distinguishes the entrance synchronization operation from the exit synchronization operation. During the entry to a critical section, termed as 'acquire', all operations with respect to the local memory variables need to be completed. During the exit, termed as 'release', all changes made by the local processor should be propagated to all other processors.
3. Entry Consistency:
   Every shared variable is assigned a synchronization variable specific to it. When the 'acquire' is to variable x, all operations related to x need to be completed with respect to that processor. When the 'release' is to variable x, all changes related to x should be propagated.
4. Local Consistency:
   Each process performs its own operations in the order defined by its program. There is no constraint on the ordering in which the write operations of other processes appear to be performed.

Many of these look similar to C++ memory order models. Can someone give a correct mapping of these concepts to C++ memory order models.

Comment: This is what I learnt from few days. I don't a better way to cross-verify what I understood. So I'm posting it as self-answered question so someone can correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Remember that we have yet no working C++ memory model, only a sketch. And a real model might be too much for either C or C++ committee to digest. But we don't know as even Java had great difficulties coming up with a model, for a safe language!

Comment: @curiousguy Isn't [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model) a memory model for C++?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether C++ memory order models are derived from these. But they do map to these consistency models pretty well.

1. Weak Ordering:
   Using C++ sequentially-consistent fences do correspond to 'synchronization operations' in weak ordering.
2. Release Consistency:
   This has two kinds (also mentioned in the Wikipedia page linked in question)
   RCsc: Usage of C++ sequentially-consistent operations do map to 'acquire' and 'release' operations in release consistency (with sequential consistency between synchronization operations).
   RCpc: Usage of C++ release-acquire operations do map to 'acquire' and 'release' operations in release consistency (with processor consistency between synchronization operations).
3. Entry Consistency:
   The nearest you can get to these in C++ is by using C++ release-consume operations. But in case, release operation does synchronize entire memory instead of only dependent operations. Perhaps, due to its complexity, C++ didn't bother to add a produce operation. Also note that, even though consume operation is there, in most implementations it is implemented as acquire. I also have heard that use of it is discouraged as of now.
   Also, by symmetry, Entry consistency may also have two types - ECsc and ECpc - though it is not mentioned in the Wikipedia. In that case, release-consume model is near to ECpc I think.
4. Local consistency:
   This is the default model of single threaded C++ program. If you are using multiple threads with shared data, then have to use relaxed atomics.

I don't know where to fit release-acquire and release-consume fences. They seem to be stronger than release consistency models, but are definitely weaker than weak ordering.

Comment: This is what I learnt from few days. I don't a better way to cross-verify what I understood. So I'm posting it as self-answered question so someone can correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That looks correct to me for weak and release.  What wikipedia describes as "weak consistency" seems to be using `relaxed` operations and plain non-atomic variables, and `atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst)` in key places to recover sequential consistency.  This is a very bad approach for C++, since you already have to use `std::atomic` for some variables.  I think that wikipedia "weak consistency" model makes more sense as a description of hardware ISAs like PowerPC where you don't have special load-acquire instructions, just plain loads/stores (and atomic RMWs), and separate barrier instructions.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that even though `relaxed` doesn't guarantee any consistency between operations on different objects, it does still guarantee coherency of multiple operations on the same object. Readers will only see values from equal or later in the modification order than their previous load. The top of the wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model) does make that distinction, and yeah, "local" is no consistency at all.  (With non-`atomic` variables you'd have undefined behaviour, so there's no usable way in C++ to not have coherency either.)

Comment: I don't understand exactly what "entry consistency" is, or what it implies for lock-free atomics, but I don't think it's as weak as release/consume. Or is it not equivalent to using a separate lock for each object with acquire/release to lock/unlock?

Comment: Regarding entry consistency, what I think is that, it applies a one way barrier like release consistency. But that barrier only affects to variables that depend on that particular synchronisation variable. And if I'm correct, mo_consume also puts restrictions on only dependent variables, variables that are not dependent can be freely reordered by the compiler.

Comment: Using lock for each object means, even though locks are associated with one object, when you use it, it constrains all operations, not only the operations that are dependent on locked objects. So I think this is release consistency rather than entry consistency.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model#Entry_consistency says it *is* a variant of Release Consistency.  Same effect by other means.  The wiki article is only a short summary, but they do talk about "critical sections", so I think they do mean the "synchronization variables" are ones you can do test-and-set on, with the "acquire" operation being an RMW.  That would explain "Concurrency cannot be seen for critical operations on the same shared variable."  And yes, this would constrain all operations, that's why it's like C++ acq_rel, not release/consume.

Comment: @PeterCordes "When an acquire is done on a synchronization variable, only those data guarded by that synchronization variable are made consistent." From [this](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs551/CourseNotes/Consistency/TypesConsistency.html) site.

Comment: By 'variant of release consistency' I guess that, both models use acquire-release pairs to mark critical section. But they differ in what is critical section. In release consistency every operation between acq-rel is critical section, whereas in entry consistency only operations that are dependent on that synchronisation variable between acq-rel is critical section. So it further weaken release consistency and gives more flexibility for optimisations. This is what I think.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes more sense, otherwise you don't need a whole model to describe it, it would just literally be release consistency with the implementation choice of using a lock for every variable.  But I don't really grok exactly how it *does* work.  If acquiring a lock only gives you visibility and for the guarded data, not everything in the other thread, that's different from `consume`; that's like release store / relaxed load which is basically nothing.

Comment: Consume implies that you can also read other data pointed-to by the actual data you loaded.  If you don't have that (and the thing you linked doesn't say so), only the actual data from the critical section itself, you'd have to make your critical sections larger, so all the data you need is guarded by the sync var.  IDK if (or how) that would be usable in general, so clearly I'm missing something, or else it's just not at all appropriate for the kinds of things `std::atomic<>` does.  Maybe it makes sense for distributed filesystems or databases or something.

Comment: Entry consistency in not relaxed load. Guarded data is not just the synchronisation variable. In a hypothetical language, `p.link(a); a=1; b=1; p.release(1);`. If this is release consistency, then both a and b will have value of 1 when p acquired. If this is entry consistency, then only a is guaranteed to have value of 1 when p is acquired. How is this release store / relaxed load?

Comment: Also, don't get convinced by me about entry consistency. I'm still learning and trying to figure things out. :)

Comment: Lock-free atomics don't need a separate synchronization variable at all, so the C++ equivalent of what you showed is `b=1;` `a.store(1, release)`, then any later load of `a` will see `1`.  (Equivalent to the next acquire of `p` in your pseudocode).  I put the `b=1` store before `a` to be consistent with your pseudocode where it precedes the `p.release(1)`.  In my the C++ version, to get `a==1` without any guarantee about `b`, you could do `a.load(relaxed)` or `a.load(consume)`.

Comment: Either way, if this is coherency-ordered after the release op, you get the `1` (even with a relaxed store, because we're asserting that the load sees the store value, instead of the the load's `p.link(a)` happening *before* the one that stored.)    `a.load(consume)` implies stuff like `arr[a]` also happening-after the release store in the writing thread, but I didn't see that in Entry consistency.  Again, I've never heard of Entry consistency before, and am just making stuff up based on those one-paragraph summaries, so it probably doesn't work like I'm imagining. At least I hope it doesn't :P

Comment: Now I get what you mean by release store / relaxed load. But if `a` isn't atomic, then you need `p` as described above.

Comment: Yes, of course.  But you're asking what the mapping is to C++ `std::atomic` where you make the shared variable itself `atomic`, instead of using a separate synchronization variable.  (Except implicitly if `atomic<T>::is_lock_free()` isn't true.)  If you want to make that explicit, I guess you could use `p.store(&a, release)` and use a consume load to get a pointer and deref it; I'm guessing that's what you meant by release / consume.